# Shall we re-create the "ctxsys"."context" type index when the procedure used creating the index has been modified?

Tags: oracle, indexing

We have the following index on a table:

```
CREATE INDEX "SCHEMA"."FINDEINTRAGURKUNDLTEIL" ON "SCHEMA"."URKUNDLTEIL" ("DATEN") 
  INDEXTYPE IS "CTXSYS"."CONTEXT"
  PARAMETERS ('datastore FINDEINTR_URKUNLD_PREF
               filter FINDEINTR_CHARSET_FILTER
               lexer FINDEINTR_LEXER
               section group findEintr_sectionGroup  
               nontransactional
               SYNC (ON COMMIT)') 
  PARALLEL 16 ;
```

The procedure attribute of the CTX preference was set as follows:

```
ctx_ddl.set_attribute ( 
    PREFERENCE_NAME => 'FINDEINTR_URKUNLD_PREF',
    ATTRIBUTE_NAME=> 'PROCEDURE',
    ATTRIBUTE_VALUE => 'FINDEINTRAG.findDatenUrkundlteil')
```

The text search works fine, the index is used properly.

Because of a change request, we have to modify the `FINDEINTRAG.findDatenUrkundlteil` code. No doubt about, that we have to recompile the modified procedure:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY "FINDEINTRAG" AS 
     procedure findDatenUrkundlteil () AS 
     BEGIN
         /*code comes here*/
     END findDatenUrkundlteil;
END FINDEINTRAG;
```

My question is: Shall we drop the `"SCHEMA"."FINDEINTRAGURKUNDLTEIL"` index and create it again? Or 
after compilation of the procedure, will the index for the new entries in the table be generated using the new procedure?

From functional point of view this would be fine, namely the change request does not impact the old data in the database and their index created by the old procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get away with `ALTER INDEX <indexname> REBUILD` rather than dropping and recreating.